# how to display mongodb date in symfony2 twig template?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, twig

I have a website listing products using symfony2 and mongodb

I added the items into mongodb with create date and need to display all items in my twig template.

For this

In my controller I passed the array itemlist  to twig template.

My twig template

```
{% for item in itemlist %}
<h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
<p>{{item.name}}</p>
{{item.createdate}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here I am not getting the item.createdate

How to directly display the mongo date in twig template?

is there any twig extension for this?

Answer (score 4):

```
{{ sampleDate.sec|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension class that might work for you:

```
class MongoDateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mongoDate_extension';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('convertMongoDate', array($this, 'convertMongoDateFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function convertMongoDateFilter(\MongoDate $mongoDate)
    {
        return new \DateTime('@' . $mongoDate->sec);
    }
}
```

Then register the class to your dependency injection container by adding the following snippet to your services.xml. Consider that you have to adjust the class path in the example.

```
<service id="twig.extension.mongo_date"
         class="Path\To\Your\Bundle\Twig\Extension\MongoDateExtension">
    <tag name="twig.extension"/>
</service>
```

The extension will convert the mongo date to a php \DateTime object. It will perform the transformation with an accuracy of seconds so if you need microseconds as well you will need to adjust the extension.

Finally in your twig template you can just use the twig date formatting extension:

```
{{ sampleDate|convertMongoDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

which will print *2013-11-05*

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced problems with timezones using **sec**.
Instead I used **toDateTime** which works fine.

```
{{ sampleDate.toDateTime|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

[MongoDate::toDateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodate.todatetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Th most simple way i found is :

```
{{ event.begin.toDateTime()|date("d/m/Y H:i:s") }}
```